# Getting data from database in web routes - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, security

I have this Laravel application, in which I want to display the name of the logged in user in the pages.. Thing is, I'm getting the data in the web.php file, like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $welcomeNames = DB::table('users')->get();
    return view('welcome', ['welcomeNames' => $welcomeNames]);
});
```

And then, in my welcome.blade.php, I return the data like this:

```
@if (!Auth::guest())

        @foreach($welcomeNames as $key => $data)
            @if ($data->name == Auth::user()->name )
                <tr>    
                <th>{{$data->name}}</th>             
                </tr>
            @endif
        @endforeach
                
        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('frm-logout').submit();" class="text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-500 underline">
            Logout
        </a>    
        <form id="frm-logout" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </form> 
        
    @else
                        
@endif
```

My question is: is this a safe practice? I don't know if getting the data from the DB in my route is safe. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is totally unnecessary, since you're just comparing it to `Auth::user()->name`, then printing out the exact same information. Drop the DB query, and just echo out `Auth::user()->name`

Comment: Hmm, i see.. But let's say i'm not printing the user, but some other information from another table, then is this a safe practice ?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest getting the whole table to pass to the blade. That just uses up way too much time and memory. You can request just the necessary information and pass it to the blade. All of this is processed by PHP, so nothing is exposed to the end-user unless you deliberately do so.

Comment: I see, but the main goal of the question is, is it safe to get data from the DB like this ?

Comment: Safe? Sure, since nothing is exposed to the user unless you expose it.

Comment: Safe, yes, but why would you do that instead of making a controller?

Answer (score 0):

It is safe as long as you do not show it somewhere where it doesn't belong. But its bad practice and shouldn't be done if not really needed. AND controllers are way more organised in any way.